# AppDelegate: call function only if theres a new notification, how?

Tags: ios, swift, function, notifications

I've got a problem since my app, evidently, calls the new notification function every time the app finished launching (in AppDelegate). How do I make my `newNotification()`-function only being called, when it's used for a new notification and not when the app started launching?

Here's the relevant code from appDelegate (mvc = MainViewController):

```
  let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    }

    let generalCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "GENERAL",
                                                 actions: [],
                                                 intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                 options: .customDismissAction)

    center.setNotificationCategories([generalCategory])

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    mvc.newNotification()

    let contentText = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "contentText")
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "The Better Life Challenge", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "\(contentText!)", arguments: nil)

    var dateInfo = DateComponents()
    dateInfo.hour = 4
    dateInfo.minute = 0
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TBLC", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You do this in method called, didRecieveRemoteNotification...this method fires when you recieve new notification, not didFinishLaunchingWithOptions..